# Doing Crosstable in Pandas like in Qlik?

Tags: python, pandas, qlikview, qliksense

I have a dataframe:

```
    df1=pd.DataFrame({
        'ID':[101,102],
        'Name':['Axel','Bob'],
        'US':['GrA','GrC'],
        'Europe':['GrB','GrD'],
        'AsiaPac':['GrZ','GrF']
     })
```

Which I want to change to this:

```
    df2=pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[101,101,101,102,102,102],
    'Name':['Axel','Axel','Axel','Bob','Bob','Bob'],
    'Region':['US','Europe','AsiaPac','US','Europe','AsiaPac'],
    'Group':['GrA','GrB','GrZ','GrC','GrD','GrF']
})
```

How do I do it? There is a crosstab function in pandas but it doesn't do this. In Qlik I would simply do

```
    Crosstable(Region,Group,2)  
    LOAD
        ID,
        Name,
        US,
        Europe,
        AsiaPac
```

And I would go from df1 to df2. How can I do this in python (pandas or otherwise)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is essentially reshaping your data from a wide format to a long format, as it's known in R parlance. In pandas, you can do this with `pd.melt`:

```
pd.melt(df1, id_vars=['ID', 'Name'], var_name='Region', value_name='Group')
#     ID  Name   Region Group
# 0  101  Axel  AsiaPac   GrZ
# 1  102   Bob  AsiaPac   GrF
# 2  101  Axel   Europe   GrB
# 3  102   Bob   Europe   GrD
# 4  101  Axel       US   GrA
# 5  102   Bob       US   GrC
```

If you need your columns sorted on `ID` or `Name` and `Group`, as in your example output, you can add `.sort_values()` to the expression:

```
pd.melt(df1, id_vars=['ID', 'Name'], var_name='Region', value_name='Group').sort_values(['ID', 'Group'])
#     ID  Name   Region Group
# 4  101  Axel       US   GrA
# 2  101  Axel   Europe   GrB
# 0  101  Axel  AsiaPac   GrZ
# 5  102   Bob       US   GrC
# 3  102   Bob   Europe   GrD
# 1  102   Bob  AsiaPac   GrF
```

Comment: What is the difference between `var_name` and `value_name`?

Answer (score 3):

You can try

1st

`stack()`

```
   df1.set_index(['ID','Name']).stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_2':'Region',0:'Group'})
Out[890]: 
    ID  Name   Region Group
0  101  Axel  AsiaPac   GrZ
1  101  Axel   Europe   GrB
2  101  Axel       US   GrA
3  102   Bob  AsiaPac   GrF
4  102   Bob   Europe   GrD
5  102   Bob       US   GrC
```

---

2nd

`pd.wide_to_long` , even it is overkill. :)

```
df1=df1.rename(columns={'AsiaPac':'Group_AsiaPac','Europe':'Group_Europe','US':'Group_US'})
pd.wide_to_long(df1,['Group'], i=['ID','Name'], j='Region',sep='_',suffix='.').reset_index()

Out[918]: 
    ID  Name   Region Group
0  101  Axel  AsiaPac   GrZ
1  101  Axel   Europe   GrB
2  101  Axel       US   GrA
3  102   Bob  AsiaPac   GrF
4  102   Bob   Europe   GrD
5  102   Bob       US   GrC
```

Comment: @AlhpaDelta Yw~